# URL replacement in java

Tags: java, string, url

I am trying to replace url with another url.

Below is the example of source url

```
http://sysserver01.internal.com/web/www/internal/projectwork/resources/injury-prevention-and-recovery/avoiding-injury/overview-of-running-injuries/
```

so this url should be replace with below url,

```
http://sysserver01.internal.com/var/www/html/injury-prevention-and-recovery/avoiding-injury/overview-of-running-injuries/
```

It means if source url comes then the part after **resources** in source url must be appended with **/var/www/html/**(and rest of part after resources in source url).

This needs to be happen with rendom set of source url that contains resources string.

I dont have enough knowldege of string manipulation. So please someone help me to solve this query. Please try to solve it in JAVA as I choose this platform for my work.

Comment: Did you try String replace method?

Comment: *"I dont have enough knowldege of string manipulation"*  See [Manipulating Characters in a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html).  In future please also show more research effort, what you have tried, and make sure to ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

```
String originalUrl = "http://sysserver01.internal.com/web/www/internal/projectwork/resources/injury-prevention-and-recovery/avoiding-injury/overview-of-running-injuries";

String newUrl = originalUrl.replaceAll("web/www/internal/projectwork/resources", "var/www/html");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String originalUrl = "http://sysserver01.internal.com/web/www/internal/projectwork/resources/injury-prevention-and-recovery/avoiding-injury/overview-of-running-injuries";

String newUrl = originalUrl.replace("web/www/internal/projectwork/resources", "var/www/html");
```

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, replace takes two chars, not two Strings.

Comment: @dragon66 Ah, so it does. [Java 1.5 String Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)